# how to use a variable in type of input

Tags: javascript, angularjs

in my form i have the label and input value who come from json like this

```
"attribut1":{
  "name":"attrib1",
  "type":"text"
},

"attribut2":{
  "name":"attrib2",
  "type":"number"
}
```

So for label i just put value.name it gaves me the name, but when i put inside the type of input value.type it doesn't work like

```
<label for="key">{{value.name}}</label>
<input type="value.type" class="form-control form-control-rounded" id="key" placeholder="">
```

I dont know how to set the type as variable, I need some help please

Comment: Add a plunkr demo or something like that. Its hard to tell from the info u have provided

Comment: please share some code and the complete json object

Comment: Add some more code! Where is input element

Comment: i added the input code right now you can see it

Answer (score 1):

Using JQuery you can set the value of input field like:

```
$("#inputFieldID").val(value.name);
$("#inputFieldID").clone().attr('type',value.type).insertAfter("#inputFieldID").prev().remove();
```

Comment: okey but i want to set the type of input as variable  like type=''value.type'' but is not working

Comment: $('#inputFieldID').clone().attr('type',value.type).insertAfter('#inputFieldID').prev().remove();

Answer (score 1):

Use double curly brace notation to set the attribute.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('DemoApp', []);

myApp.controller('DemoCtrl', function() {
  this.inputs = {
    "attribut1": {
      "name": "attrib1",
      "type": "text"
    },

    "attribut2": {
      "name": "attrib2",
      "type": "number"
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="DemoApp" ng-controller="DemoCtrl as ctrl">

  <ng-container ng-repeat="a in ctrl.inputs">
    <label>{{a.name}}</label>
    <input type="{{a.type}}">
  </ng-container>

</div>
```

Comment: yeah it works for me thanks a lot i forget the double curly brace

Comment: @developer : glad to help

Answer (score 0):

I think you can only do it with Javascript, so just use something like this to get the variable inside.

```
<label id="key_label" for="key">{{value.name}}</label>
<script>
document.getElementById("key_label").innerHTML = myObj.name;
</script>
```

Comment: i edited my question it was to set the type as variable the response before this it works for me thanks for help